# Sketching the graph of a cubic function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Consider $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the function $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$. I have to sketch the graph of this function. I can find the solutions of $f'(x) = 0$ but it is difficult to find the intervals in which the function is increasing or decreasing since nothing is mentioned about $a$, $b$ and $c $, i.e. whether they are positive or negative and their relative positions in the number line.

Comment: Then you might need to discuss the relevant aspects of the graph in terms of the parameters.

Comment: The derivative of $f(x)= x^3+ ax^2+ bx+ c$ is $f'(x)= 3x^2+ 2ax+ b$ and the boundaries between intervals where f'(x)> 0 and f'(x)< 0 are where $f'(x)= 3x^2+ ax+ b= 0$.  That is a quadratic equation so use the *quadratic formula*:  $x= \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2- 12b}}{6}$.

Comment: The question, as stated, gives way too few details to give a decent sketch. You could break it down into two or three cases and give a general idea of the overall shape. Do you think that is what is wanted?

Answer (score 5):

WLOG, $a=c=0$ and $b\in\{-1,0,1\}$ ! Why ? Because

1. translating the curve horizontally, i.e. turning the equation to
   $$(x+t)^3+a(x+t)^2+b(x+t)+c\\=x^3+(a+3t)x^2+(2at+3t^2+b)x+at^2+bt+t^3+c$$ allows you to choose $t$ such that the quadratic coefficient vanishes.
2. varying the constant term in the general cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ merely translates the curve vertically, which does not alter its shape. So the resulting constant term after the above manipulation, with the substituted value of t, can be ignored and the shape of the graph remains the same.
3. Next, by scaling $x$ with $x=\sqrt{|b|}y$ you have
   $$x^3+bx=|b|\sqrt{|b|}y^3+b\sqrt{|b|}y=|b|\sqrt{|b|}(y^3\pm y)$$ and when $b=0$, just $x^3$.

So we can show the three *canonical* shapes of any cubic, obtained by linear transformations of the coordinates.

[image]

The curve has a central symmetry at a single inflection point, and two extrema or none.

Comment: this is quite good. I would not have known what to say. I see, extrema are local min or local max

Comment: @WillJagy: with a variant of this transformation, you reduce a cubic equation to one of the forms $4x^3\pm3x=c$, that has an easy trigonometric or hyperbolic solution.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n5latnnvfp) an interactive graph with the final three cases.

Comment: @harry: this is missing the RHS of the equation.

Comment: Did you mean the equation in (3), as in both the terms in x and in y have to be specified? I just thought that effectively meant constant$* (x^3 \pm x)=0$. y is just a scaled version of x, right? So isn't this enough?